# JavaFX - Get input of TextField and write it to XML

Tags: java, xml, javafx

In short:
I want to write the context of a TextField to a File.

More Detailed:
With a Button and then a FileChooser I read in a XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
   <comment>ABCDEF</comment>
   <entry key="variableName1">variableName1Content</entry>
   <entry key="variableName2">variableName2Content</entry>
   <entry key="variableName4">variableName4Content</entry>
</properties>
```

and filter the content that it is displayed in a way where the entry key values (e.g. "variableName1") are labels and the contents (e.g. "variableName1Content") are the text of a TextField. I do it with "**readXml()**." I also add the variableName (e.g. "variableName1") and the corresponding TextField to a HashMap, because I want to get the text of the TextField the user entered there. I use the HashMap in **"saveNewValues()**.
For now I just want to add the text in the TextFields in the new File ("tmpFile.xml"), but my created File is empty. In the next step I want the original xml to be overwritten with the new values the user has entered, so that the xml looks exactly the same, but with the new values.
Thanks in advance.

**Controller**:

```java
package application;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Controller {

   @FXML
   private ScrollPane scrollPaneXml;

   private File readXml;

   private GridPane gridPaneXml = new GridPane();

   private HashMap<String, TextField> hashMapXml = new HashMap<>();

   public void readXml() throws IOException {
      FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
      Stage thisStage = (Stage) scrollPaneXml.getScene().getWindow();
      readXml = fc.showOpenDialog(thisStage);

      if (readXml != null) {

         int gridPaneXmlRow = 0;
         BufferedReader br = null;
         String variableName;
         String variableContent;

         gridPaneXml.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20 ,20));
         gridPaneXml.setHgap(20);
         gridPaneXml.setVgap(20);

         scrollPaneXml.setContent(gridPaneXml);
         scrollPaneXml.setFitToHeight(true);
         scrollPaneXml.setFitToWidth(true);

         try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(readXml));
            String text;
            while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {

               if (text.startsWith("\uFEFF")) {
                  continue;
               }

               // Check for "<comment>"
               if (text.contains("<comment>") && !(text.startsWith("<!--"))) {

                  // Content between first "<" and last ">"
                  variableName = text.substring(text.indexOf("<") + 1, text.indexOf(">"));

                  // Content between first ">" und second "<"
                  variableContent = text.substring(text.indexOf(">") + 1, text.indexOf("<", text.indexOf("<") + 1));

                  Label label = new Label(variableName);

                  TextField txtField = new TextField();
                  txtField.setText(variableContent);
                  txtField.setPrefWidth(300);

                  hashMapXml.put(variableName, txtField);

                  gridPaneXml.add(label, 0, gridPaneXmlRow);
                  gridPaneXml.add(txtField, 1, gridPaneXmlRow);
                  gridPaneXmlRow += 1;

               } else if (text.contains("<entry") && !(text.startsWith("<!--"))) {

                  // Content between "=" and second quotation mark
                  variableName = text.substring(text.indexOf("=") + 2, text.indexOf("\"", text.indexOf("\"") + 1));

                  variableContent = text.substring(text.indexOf(">")+1, text.indexOf("<", text.indexOf("<") + 1));

                  TextField txtField = new TextField();
                  txtField.setText(variableContent);
                  txtField.setPrefWidth(300);

                  Label label = new Label(variableName);

                  hashMapXml.put(variableName, txtField);

                  gridPaneXml.add(label, 0, gridPaneXmlRow);
                  gridPaneXml.add(txtField, 1, gridPaneXmlRow);
                  gridPaneXmlRow += 1;
               }
            }
         } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         } finally {
            br.close();
         }

      }
   }

   public void saveNewValues() {

      BufferedReader br = null;
      BufferedWriter bw = null;

      String variableName;


      for (Map.Entry<String, TextField> entry : hashMapXml.entrySet()) {
         String key = entry.getKey();
         TextField txtField = entry.getValue();

         try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(readXml));
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\abcdef\\tmpFile.xml"));

            String text;

            while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {

               if (text.contains("<comment>") && !(text.startsWith("<!--"))) {

                  // Content between first "<" and next ">"
                  variableName = text.substring(text.indexOf("<") + 1, text.indexOf(">"));

                  if (variableName.equals(key)) {

                     bw.write(txtField.getText());
                  }
               } else if(text.contains("<entry") && !(text.startsWith("<!--"))) {

                  // Content between "=" and second quotation mark
                  variableName = text.substring(text.indexOf("=") + 2, text.indexOf("\"", text.indexOf("\"") + 1));

                  if (variableName.equals(key)) {

                     bw.write(txtField.getText());
                  }
               }
            }
         } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The **fxml file** is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="657.0" prefWidth="1023.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#readXml" text="Read XML" />
      <ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPaneXml" layoutX="158.0" layoutY="101.0" prefHeight="455.0" prefWidth="707.0">
        <content>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
        </content>
      </ScrollPane>
      <Button layoutX="23.0" layoutY="612.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#saveNewValues" text="Save new Values" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: I advise using a library to parse/create xml rather than coding it manually (e.g. jackson, gson, jaxb).  Makery provide a [jaxb+javafx example](https://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-tutorial/part5/), but other libraries will also work well if you prefer them.

Comment: However, you appear to be using standard [java properties](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html#loadFromXML(java.io.InputStream)) stored in XML format, so you can use `loadFromXML` to load the data into a properties structure, keep the properties as the model for your UI, allowing it to update the properties, then, when needed store the updated properties using `storeToXML`.

Comment: Given they are properties, I am wondering [why you choose to use XML at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470763/whats-the-purpose-of-properties-loadfromxml-and-properties-storetoxml-metho), rather than saving as a text file in name=value form, which most property files read by Java use.

Comment: I didn't know about these libraries. I think I will read into it.